# RStudio error using View with character vectors longer than 100

Tags: r, vector, rstudio

I hope I'm not missing something obvious here, but I can't seem to figure this one out.

I'm using RStudio 0.99.489 on Mac OS 10.11.1 and when I try to use `View(myCharVec)` with a vector of length greater than 100, I get the following error:

> Error in View : 'names' attribute [x] must be the same length as the vector [1]

(Where x is a number *seemingly* related to the length of the vector.)

`names(myCVec)` and `attributes(myCVec)` both return `NULL`, `class(myCVec)` returns `"character"`, and `str(myCVec)` returns `'chr [1:length(myCVec)] "a" "x" "M" ...'` as expected.

Some samples & results:

```
myCVec <- paste(sample(c(letters, LETTERS), 100, replace = TRUE))
View(myCVec)  #(Opens viewer normally.)

myCVec <- paste(sample(c(letters, LETTERS), 101, replace = TRUE))
View(myCVec)
Error in View : 'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]

myCVec <- paste(sample(c(letters, LETTERS), 490, replace = TRUE))
View(myCVec)
Error in View : 'names' attribute [5] must be the same length as the vector [1]

myCVec <- paste(sample(c(letters, LETTERS), 200000, replace = TRUE))
View(myCVec)
Error in View : 'names' attribute [1981] must be the same length as the vector [1]
```

The `edit()` function opens the character vector without any problems.

`View()` works in R and used to work in previous installations (perhaps 2 or three builds ago?) of RStudio. (I haven't had time to look for a solution until now.)

Comment: Can confirm error is reproducible with Ubuntu and RStudio 99.489.

Comment: I can confirm the error with RStudio version `0.99.489`. It works with at least the version `0.98.1103` of RStudio. Too many troubles with the last updates. Keep working with version `0.98.1103`.

Comment: It breaks at `View(rep("string",51))` on OS X

Comment: Using `View` or `edit` is not the R-way.

Comment: `View` is a valid function in`utils`, ergo it _should_ work whether one believes it's "R-ish" or not @42-

Comment: @42- I use `View` to quickly look at what I have and only came across `edit` when trying to solve the problem, thanks for the input though.

Comment: @Pascal Thanks. Even though the issue isn't that big of a deal, I will go back to `0.98.1103` for now. Hope these troubles get worked out soon.